# Ways to only process new(index after last run) data in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way to get the date and time that an elastic search document was written?

I am running es queries via spark and would prefer **NOT** to look through all documents that I have already processed. Instead I would like read the only documents that were ingested between the last time the program ran and now.

What is the best most efficient way to do this?

I have looked at;

- **updating** to add a field with an array with booleans for if its been looked at by which analytic. The negative is waiting for the update to occur.
- **index per time frame** method, which would be to break down the current indexes into smaller ones so by hour.The negative I see is the number of open file descriptors.
- **??**

Elasticsearch version 5.6

Comment: Add a counter to your documents and increase that each time you "process" that document. There used to be a `_timestamp` but was removed in 5.x. But still that timestamp wasn't the exact time the document has been indexed into ES ;-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I posted the question on the [elasticsearch discussion board](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/only-process-newly-indexed-documents/111785) and it appears using the [ingest pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.1/accessing-data-in-pipelines.html#accessing-ingest-metadata) is the best option.

Answer (score 2):

> I am running es queries via spark and would prefer NOT to look through
>   all documents that I have already processed. Instead I would like read
>   the only documents that were ingested between the last time the
>   program ran and now.

A workaround could be :

While inserting data using **Logstash** to Elasticsearch, Logstash appends a **@timestamp** key to the document which represents the time (in UTC) at which the document is created or we can use an **[ingest pipline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/breaking_50_mapping_changes.html#_literal__ttl_literal_and_literal__timestamp_literal_cannot_be_created)**

After that we can query based on the timestamp.

For more on this please have a look at :

1. [Mapping changes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/breaking_50_mapping_changes.html#_literal__timestamp_literal_and_literal__ttl_literal)
2. [There is no way to ask ES to insert a timestamp at index time](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/15644)

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch doesn't have such functionality.

You need manually save with each document date. In this case you will be able to search by date range.

Comment: So you are saying to add a field that holds the date/time written or now()?